# how to setup custom content structures

Tags: theme-development, pages, page-template

I have some custom pages I need to develop, and I want them to be easily edited by my client.  The problem is that the markup is fairly complicated, I want to be able to give them the ability to edit a list without touching the raw html...what is the proper way to do this in WP?

Comment: I'd use this plugin as its end user friendly: [ACF Plugin](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/)

Comment: I will second Mikode on that.  Elliot Condon's Advanced Custom Fields is a great solution to make complex content easy to edit for your client.  Buy the Pro license, you will not be disappointed